# Cannot disable Windows Hotkeys through Registry or Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11

In allot of web articles and even answers to questions about disabling windows hotkeys such as `Win`+ `P`  or `Win`+ `A`, the following three solutions are always proposed:

- [Disable the Windows Key Shortcuts with Local Group Policy Editor](https://www.howtogeek.com/282080/how-to-disable-the-built-in-windows-key-shortcuts/)
- [Disable the Windows Key Shortcuts by Editing the Registry](https://www.howtogeek.com/282080/how-to-disable-the-built-in-windows-key-shortcuts/)
- [Disable **specific** Windows Key Shortcuts by Editing the Registry](https://winbuzzer.com/2023/03/04/how-to-disable-the-windows-key-in-windows-11-windows-10-xcxwbt/)

I have tried all three solutions but they never work for me, even after Restarting my PC.
I tried to follow the first one, an exported example of this registry key on my PC is:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoWinKeys"=dword:00000001
```

After logging out, the windows shortcuts continue to work just fine. I then tried the second solution:

[image]

Again I restarted my PC, all the shortcuts work. I then tried to disable individual shortcuts with the last solution, in this case `Win`+ `P`. The following is an exported example of the registry key on my PC:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Advanced]
"DisabledHotkeys"=hex(2):50,00,00,00
```

After signing out and back in, the `Win`+`P` shortcut continues to work.

All three solutions are in place on my PC, yet windows shortcut keys continue to work. I was expecting some of them to be near impossible to disable such as `Win`+`L` but I cant even seem to disable any.

Is this a common issue? Could there be another setting that could be overriding these settings?

I am not looking for an AutoHotkey solution.

I am on Windows 11 Pro, with a single admin account.

Comment: All 3 methods should have worked. (1) Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (2) If no errors were found, this is strange, but you could also try to map the key to, say, the Shift key. See [link](https://winbuzzer.com/2021/11/29/how-to-remap-keys-on-windows-11-or-windows-10-xcxwbt/). Let me know the results.

Comment: Remap to null to disable completely.

Comment: @KeithMiller, hey thank you, its been a while since I had a go at this, I will give it another ago and try your suggestion, by the way when you say "Remap to null" are you reffering to the registry (regEdit) method?

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings: Editing the registry, yes, either by merging a `.reg` file or with **PowerShell** commands/script. I have some **PowerShell** code to create the binary value necessary. Will post when I get back to my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "kill" the Windows key by remapping it to the *null* scancode `0x0000`.

Per the [documentation](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc), the scancodes for the Windows keys are:

| key | ScanCode |
| --- | --- |
| LWinKey | 0xe05b |
| RWinKey | 0xe05c |

Because the value you want to create will be under HKLM, you have run the following from an elevated/Admin PowerShell console:

```
$NullKey        = [byte[]]($null,$null)
$LeftWindows    = [byte[]](0x5b,0xe0)
$RightWindows   = [byte[]](0x5c,0xe0)

$RemapCount     = 2

$ReMap          = [byte[]](
                          [Byte[]]::new(8) +
   [BitConverter]::GetBytes(1+$RemapCount) +
                   $NullKey + $LeftWindows +
                  $NullKey + $RightWindows +
                          [Byte[]]::new(4)
)

$Splat = @{
    'Path'  = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
    'Name'  = 'ScanCode Map'
    'Value' = $Remap
    'Force' = $True
}
New-ItemProperty @Splat

###   To supress output, use:
###   [Void]New-ItemProperty @Splat
```

You can copy and paste the above code into an Admin PowerShell console as a single block and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exdecute. Restart the coputer for the change to take effect.

Comment: Wow it was that easy?? well you make it look easy, I am sure. I will save this answer and code for prosperity. Thank you Keith

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings: You're welcome. And thanks for the compliment -- I tried to set it up so that it's easily expanded by defining additional key-scancode variables and rremapping pairs, and modifying the count and array construction.